# js while loop not meeting conditions

Tags: node.js, while-loop

I write a program, that plays a random tennis game, and returns an array of scores. at the end of the program I have a while loop, that is not working correctly. I have a function, that does all the random points and pushing it to an array, so here is the loop

```
while(true){
    lvl();
    if(p1>=3){
        if(g1>=2){
            scr.push("Player 1 win");
            return false
        }
    }
    if(p2>=3){
        if(g2>=2){
            scr.push("Player 2 win");
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

if I leave it be while(true), the only condition, that is going to be met is my computers crush, if I change it to something more like while(p1<10) it will anyway run the loop, until p1 is 9, not worrying about the if statements, that have to terminate the loop in certain conditions. How can I fix this? for information g1=p1-p2(and also have the same for p2). Also while playing the game, even if all stop signals are met, it continues to play, untill p1=9

```
  [ [ 'Love-all' ],
  [ 'Fifteen', 'Love' ],
  [ 'Thirty', 'Love' ],
  [ 'Thirty', 'Fifteen' ],
  [ 'Forty', 'Fifteen' ],
  [ 'Forty', 'Thirty' ],
  [ 'Deuce' ],
  [ 'Advantage player 1', 'Forty' ],
  [ 'Deuce' ],
  [ 'Advantage player 1', 'Advantage player 2' ],
  [ 'Advantage player 1', 'Advantage player 2' ],
  [ 'Advantage player 1', 'Advantage player 2' ],
  [ 'Advantage player 1', 'Advantage player 2' ],
  [ 'Advantage player 1', 'Advantage player 2' ],
  [ 'Advantage player 1', 'Advantage player 2' ] ]
```

here is what the console shows

Comment: How are the values for `p1`, `p2`, `g1` and `g2` being updated?

Comment: If the loop is never exited then clearly the `if` conditions leading to the `return` statements are never true.

Comment: if(Math.random()<0.5){
            p1++;
        } else {
            p2++;
        }

Comment: What does `lvl()` do?  Does it modify the values of `p1`, `g1`, `p2`, and `g2`?  `while(true)` loops only work in node.js Javascript for synchronous code, they do not work if you have any asynchronous I/O anywhere in the loop.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, My mistake was assigning g1 and g2=p1-p2(and vice versa), all I needed was 2 functions, that would count that g1 and g2

Answer (score 0):

Your computer is crashing because you are probably using 100% CPU utilization or something close to that. You typically don't want to `while(true)` without some sort `delay` in there where the CPU isn't CONSTANTLY computing something all the time in the same thread. Additionally, you want to get out of the `while(true)` with a `break` statement instead of a `return` statement.

Comment: still the same, I'm pretty sure that all conditions for finishing the loop are met, and that is p1 or p2 has 3 or more points, p1-p2(or vice versa) is 2 or more